# Loading page issue

Tags: javascript, loading

I'm using the Codrops page preloading effect. Since it's a demo they didn't implement something that really makes the progress bar loading as much as the page does. I need this to reveal the website only when it's fully loaded and not after an animation time.
This is the js code:

```
(function() {

var support = { animations : Modernizr.cssanimations },
    container = document.getElementById( 'ip-container' ),
    header = container.querySelector( 'header.ip-header' ),
    loader = new PathLoader( document.getElementById( 'ip-loader-circle' ) ),
    animEndEventNames = { 'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd', 'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd', 'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd', 'animation' : 'animationend' },
    // animation end event name
    animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];

function init() {
    var onEndInitialAnimation = function() {
        if( support.animations ) {
            this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndInitialAnimation );
        }

        startLoading();
    };

    // disable scrolling
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );

    // initial animation
    classie.add( container, 'loading' );

    if( support.animations ) {
        container.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndInitialAnimation );
    }
    else {
        onEndInitialAnimation();
    }
}

function startLoading() {
    // simulate loading something..
    var simulationFn = function(instance) {
        var progress = 0,
            interval = setInterval( function() {
                progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );

                instance.setProgress( progress );

                // reached the end
                if( progress === 1 ) {
                    classie.remove( container, 'loading' );
                    classie.add( container, 'loaded' );
                    clearInterval( interval );

                    var onEndHeaderAnimation = function(ev) {
                        if( support.animations ) {
                            if( ev.target !== header ) return;
                            this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndHeaderAnimation );
                        }

                        classie.add( document.body, 'layout-switch' );
                        window.removeEventListener( 'scroll', noscroll );
                    };

                    if( support.animations ) {
                        header.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndHeaderAnimation );
                    }
                    else {
                        onEndHeaderAnimation();
                    }
                }
            }, 80 );
    };

    loader.setProgressFn( simulationFn );
}

function noscroll() {
    window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
}

init();
})();
```

Thank you in advice!

Andrea

Comment: have you also loaded `Modernizr`?

Comment: Yes i did. The script is perfectly working but as you can see it's made for a demo so it doesn't really check for loaded content. Please help me :)